# ethernet port Pin constraint for Zedboard (phy0_dv pin ??)

Tags: vhdl, embedded-linux, fpga

I am attaching a image file which has the necessary pin constraint for our board but I wanted to run an application on zedboard so I needed to find the corresponding constraint for the gigabit ethernet port pin constraint for zed board. I found out all but "phy0_dv"? which pin corresponds to the phy0_dv on zedboard. 
here is the pin constraint pdf for the zedboard 
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/zc702_zvik/ug850-zc702-eval-bd.pdf
On the page number 69, pin contraint are there for zed board I can replace all the contraint but phy0-dv which pin should be there for this ? 
and here are the pin contraint image file for our board: 
[image]

Comment: If your board is already fabricated, examine the schematic or layout to determine where the pin is connected.  You might also see if you can extract the information from sample projects.  If all else fails you can write a temporary design to toggle possible I/Os, or read the I/Os as you externally drive them with a low voltage source - presumably you could do this with jtag boundary scan alone without needed to develop a design.

Answer (score 1):

The Xilinx documentation identifies the PHY as a Marvell 88E1116R which only supports the RGMII interface. There is no independent RXDV signal on that variant as it has been combined with RXERR as a double clocked control signal. The RX_CTRL signal indicates DV only on the rising edge of the clock.

The UCF you provided is for a board that uses the older MII interface which is limited to FastEthernet speeds (see 40 ns clock constraint). You are apparently trying to use code that isn't set up for hardware with an MII. You will need to alter the design you want to run so that it uses a MAC with MII support. If you have all of the design files you should be able to do that by regenerating a new MAC in CoreGen with the needed changes and rewiring the PHY interface.